# why npm-audit fails for react-native-unimodule

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-audit, react-native-unimodules

I am trying to run `npm audit` on my **react-native** project which originally was an expo project and ejected to bare workflow. When I run `npm audit`, I get

```
npm ERR! code ELOCKVERIFY
npm ERR! Errors were found in your package-lock.json, run  npm install  to fix them.
npm ERR!     Invalid: lock file's react-native-unimodules@0.9.1 does not satisfy react-native-unimodules@^0.7.0

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/kislam/.npm/_logs/2020-06-04T04_13_14_375Z-debug.log
```

the detail log is as follows

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/Users/kislam/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/kislam/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'audit'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.5
3 info using node@v12.14.0
4 verbose npm-session bcb02cea1f031e3c
5 verbose stack Error: Errors were found in your package-lock.json, run  npm install  to fix them.
5 verbose stack     Invalid: lock file's react-native-unimodules@0.9.1 does not satisfy react-native-unimodules@^0.7.0
5 verbose stack     at /Users/kislam/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/audit.js:184:19
6 verbose cwd /Users/kislam/bunnings/repos/trades-mobile-app
7 verbose Darwin 19.4.0
8 verbose argv "/Users/kislam/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.0/bin/node" "/Users/kislam/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.0/bin/npm" "audit"
9 verbose node v12.14.0
10 verbose npm  v6.14.5
11 error code ELOCKVERIFY
12 error Errors were found in your package-lock.json, run  npm install  to fix them.
12 error     Invalid: lock file's react-native-unimodules@0.9.1 does not satisfy react-native-unimodules@^0.7.0
13 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

The `package.json` has the following associated versions

```
"expo": "~37.0.3",
"react-native": "~0.61.4",
"react-native-unimodules": "~0.9.0",
```

Cannot figure out where `npm-audit` is getting `react-native-unimodules@^0.7.0` from.